# Google Maps not working on Angular JS after changing view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, google-maps

I am making a mobile app using cordova with Angular JS and Google Maps API. 
On my home screen I have 3 tabs. The third tab is an integration with Google Maps. The first time I enter on the third tab, the map load normally and everything runs perfect. 
But, when I change to another view that has another controller and go back to the view and controller of the Google Maps, it won't load.

Here is the code I run everytime I change to tab 3 (Where is the Google Maps).

```
$rootScope.mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-18.894608, -48.260980),
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};


$rootScope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), $rootScope.mapOptions);
```

Here is the HTML of the view

```
<div id="map-canvas" style="height: 90%; width: 100%"></div>
```

I am stuck on this problem and any help would be much appreciate.
Obs: If you need some more information about the code, just ask.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your map-canvas div under some ng-if condition, it will work definitely.

```
<div ng-if="showMap" id="map-canvas" style="height: 90%; width: 100%"></div>
```

Comment: Are you changing $scope.showMap = true, in your controller ?

Comment: I used ng-if="true" on the div. Is the same thing right?

Comment: No  ng-if="true" will not work, I guess due to code optimisation, it will be ignored. You should use some $scope variable and change it to "true" when you are coming back to third tab.

Comment: between tabs the google maps works normally. I click on tab 3, the map loads perfect. If i click on tab 1 and go back to tab 3, the maps will continue to work. The content of tabs are all in the same "homeController", i only switch the view on each tab. The problem is to load the map after a change to another view with another controller.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved adding a timeout function before calling the Google Maps API.

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
      //google maps code
},100);
```